# Hyperledger Fabric: Error in running ./byfn.sh -m up

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

Following the hyperledger fabric documentation on Creating your first network:
(My docker is also running, and I am working on windows 10)
`$byfn.sh -m generate` works perfectly. Unfortunately `byfn.sh -m up` gives errors:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7g4A.jpg)

Comment: Can you make sure the Docker is actually running:  "docker info" ?
If you get an error running the "docker info" command, make sure you actually launch Docker using the "Docker for Windows" icon on the desktop

Comment: It is running. `docker info` works normally.

Comment: the other solution would be to launch your command Window with administrator privileges

Comment: can u upload the image with better quality, not visible!